# Hive error when running from hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am following this document to test the sentiment analysis - can someone please help me out -- thanks!!

```
[root@sandbox ~]# hive -f hiveddl.sql
15/04/12 15:43:23 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.optimize.mapjoin.mapreduce does not exist
15/04/12 15:43:23 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.heapsize does not exist
15/04/12 15:43:23 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
15/04/12 15:43:23 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join.noconditionaltask does not exist

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Added [json-serde-1.1.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar] to class path
Added resources: [json-serde-1.1.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar]
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.AbstractPrimitiveJavaObjectInspector.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/primitive/PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils$PrimitiveTypeEntry;)V
```

#

Answer (score 0):

There is already this issue reported and answered on github:

[Github issue link](https://github.com/hortonworks/hadoop-tutorials/issues/30)

Comment: The link is broken. Do you have another reference?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain I don't' remember the topic of the issue reported on Github. I cannot update the broken link, sorry.